# In nodejs, error regarding a module

Tags: node.js

While running a javascript program in nodejs,say **sample.js** which contains some "formidable" module i got some errors saying can not find module "formidable" what is the reason for this error and how can i get resolved.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'formidable'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/paxterra/Desktop/server8.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too broad and I doubt it can be answerable. Could you edt question and give some **small and relevant** snippets of the code ? (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: firstly check whether 'formidable' folder is there in node_module folder which is placed parallel to your simple.js

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have a line of code that calls require() like

```
require("formidable")
```

Or

```
require("./formidable")
```

If "formidable" is an NPM module, it is not installed.  If it is a module that you wrote, the relative path passed into require() is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer why the error is coming like that.
It's because I haven't installed formidable module in to my npm.
For installing the "formidable" module, use the following command:

`npm install formidable@latest --save`